# Execute Javascript on multiple tabs at the same time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to open a specific link with the class `author-name` using Javascript, on the browser console.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("author-name");
for (let item of list) { window.open(item.href, "_self"); }
```

This code works for a single tab, but I would like to execute the same on multiple tabs at the same time.

I think this can be done using one of the available [`chrome.tabs` methods](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs), but I am unsure how to approach this.

Comment: Use TamperMonkey

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery like so:

```
$(".btnClick").click(function(event){
   $(".author-name").each(function(){
      window.open($(this).attr("href"), "_blank");
   });
});
```

I bind the click event to btnClick class to trigger the opening of tabs.